# Who am I, if not Lewisoff?

Tags: riddle, movies

*I'll help you get across a river. 

Once unrecognised in Fischer's song, 

Later I found fame alone 

And also as a US state.*

**Who am I?**

Hint 1:

> Concentrate on lines 1, 3, and 4. Line 2 and the title should be used only as checks to ensure your answer is right. They're there to make sure the answer is unique, and the way they fit it is rather twisted (but should become clear once you have the right idea).

Hint 2:

> The answer is not actually a US state.

<sub>To be accepted, an answer must explain all lines including the title. But any serious attempt at a solution will get an upvote from me.</sub>

Comment: If not CARROLL-OFF, then perhaps WASHINGT-ON or DODGS-ON.

Comment: Maybe Wisc-ons-in? In the lyrics of this song http://lyrics.wikia.com/Tom_Schilling:Fischer%27s_Song it says 'Off is in'. And together with once=ons, and off=in...

Comment: Nice ideas from both of you, but it's probably better to think about the title only at the end (see the new hint).

Comment: Great riddle! All the lines point to the answer in a clever and satisfying way.

Comment: @xnor Thanks a lot! :-) I was worried it might be too hard, especially line 2, but [PSE's top riddle-solver](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/riddle/topusers) cracked it in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are:

> HARRISON FORD.

I'll help you get across a river.

> There are a few things that do this... a bridge, **a ford**, a boat, a raft, Charon.

Once unrecognised in Fischer's song,

> Ford was uncredited on a film called: "Dead Heat on a Merry-Go-Round". Wild Man *Fischer*'s most famous song is called *Merry Go Round*.

Later I found fame alone

> ALONE -> SOLO. Han Solo was played by Harrison Ford.

And also as a US state.

> Indiana Jones is one of Ford's main sources of fame.

The title:

> If you are not Lewis-off... maybe you are Harris-on :)

Comment: Well done! I was beginning to get the feeling this one was too hard, but you've cracked it in the end. +1 and accept.

Comment: It was really hard :p But clever :D

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Texas

I'll help you get across a river

> The war against Mexico made Texas troops cross the Rio Grande

Once unrecognized in Fischer's song

> One of his songs is The Vessel. Or something with the word vessel in it. A battleship of Texas was called the USS Texas I believe.

Later found fame alone

> Won the Texas Revolution by itself and joined the US later. Battle of the Alamo, anyone?

And also a US state

> Texas joined the US shortly after the Texas Revolution.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't right, but +1 since it fits most of the clues (not the Carrolloff clue, and the Fischer line is a bit of a stretch).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is

> Carolina (North or South)

I'll help you get across a river

> There were several ships called Caroline

Later I found fame alone

> May refer to Caroline affair (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caroline_affair) or Hurricane Caroline (1975) or even Hurricanes HNL team

Getting back to the title and second line

> @Enigma guessed about words "Off is in" in Tom Schilling's song. So, how about just replace "off" in "Carrolloff" with "in" and we'll get something close to "Caroline"

Comment: Why found fame *alone*? Also there's no link between the title and the second line; they're both hard (harder than Carrolloff->Caroline!) but in different ways. +1 for a good try though :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is

> Washington.

Who am I, if not Carrolloff?

> no idea woo (likely a play on words as mentioned, Carrolloff -> Carrollon -> Washington)

I'll help you get across a river.

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Washington%27s_crossing_of_the_Delaware_River

Once unrecognised in Fischer's song,

> no idea woo

Later I found fame alone

> first president obviously

And also as a US state.

> Washington is a state.

Obviously this is only half complete.
Also credit to Gamow for having the idea.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't right (the "no idea woo" parts are going to trip you up).

Answer (score -1):

Only partial answer

Are you:

> Mississippi?

/'ll help you get across a river.

> Mississippi is name of a ship as well

Once unrecognised in Fischer's song,

> No idea who that is or what song

Later I found fame alone

> Don't know

And also as a US state.

> It is a US state

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid you're way off. I'll add a hint later today if nobody else gets it.

Answer (score -1):

ok this is a huge guess

is it:

> New Orleans

not carrollof but

> Carrollton New Orleans

Ill' help you get accros the river

> new orleans harbor

fischer

> ok I'm wrong

fame

> sorry I dont know :'(

and also a us state

> ok on this ons is correct :D

Comment: Well, if you know it's wrong, why not delete the answer? :-) You can always post a second answer if you have a new idea.