# Give me an answer that fit this riddle - What am I?

Tags: riddle

I am fast like an arrow but slow like a turtle
I  play like a Cello but with a  silence echo
I am long like a Metro but not quite the rainbow
Give me an answer that fit this riddle!

Hint:

> Many have guessed but none are correct
>  Poorly rhymed, now I regret
>  Here comes another hint
>  Stand under the Sun and you will win

Comment: To the person who tried to close this question because it's too broad: I don't even know one answer let alone "too many possible answers". I think a close vote is extremely pedantic at this point in time.

Comment: Thanks Jordy, I too have no idea why it is considered too broad

Comment: In my opinion this question could be considered a bit broad as there are only 3 lines of information, while most of the riddles have at least 5-6 lines.

Comment: @leoll2 Please see my hint that have just added

Comment: @leoll2 Short riddles aren't necessarily badly written or too broad, e.g. [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5451/5373) and [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10111/who-am-i-if-not-lewisoff) were both well received and nobody managed to find a second solution that fit all the clues.

Comment: For hint 3 they're all 2 syllables? I see no other relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is

> a shadow.

Like: arrow, turtle, Cello, Metro

> The shadow of each of these resembles the original.

... with a silence echo

> This means the echo is silent - shadows are silent, leaving no echoes.

... not quite the rainbow

> Rainbows are caused by bent light, not blocked light, so rainbows don't fit the usual way shadows are made.

Give me an answer that fit this riddle!

> 'Shadow' rhymes with 'echo' and 'rainbow'.

Hint:

> "Poorly rhymed": 'turtle' and 'riddle' doesn't quite rhyme with 'rainbow'. Also, "stand under the sun" - a good way to make a shadow.

Comment: Nicely done! +1

Answer (score 4):

Maybe too obvious given line 2, but I've managed to make it fit in some interesting and cryptic ways!

> A violin.

*I am fast like an arrow but slow like a turtle*

> You can play violin music both quickly (**allegro**) and slowly (**adagio**).

*I play like a Cello but with a silence echo*

> A violin certainly plays like a cello; I'm not sure what "with a silence echo" means though.

*I am long like a Metro but not quite the rainbow*

> Buskers might be found on the Metro playing a violin. A violin **bow** is not quite the same word as "rainbow".

*Give me an answer that fit this riddle!*

> "fit this riddle" is a Spoonerism of "rit this fiddle", and although "rit" is meaningless, a **fiddle** is another word for a violin!

Comment: Great attempt but not the answer!  I've given out another hint!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're a

> Radio Wave

I am fast like an arrow but slow like a turtle

> You travel at the speed of light, but you're a slow way to transmit information.

I play like a Cello but with a silence echo

> Radio waves can be converted into sounds, but nobody can hear your echo.

I am long like a Metro but not quite the rainbow

> Your wavelength can be very very large, though we don't see radio waves in the rainbow (just visible light).

Give me an answer that fit this riddle!

> Fit is a commonly used term when you talk about curves in math, in this case a wave.

Comment: Good guess but not the answer!  Line 4 doesn't quite 'fit' =)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are

> A cat.

I am fast like an arrow but slow like a turtle

> Cats have a high top speed, but often remain totally motionless while hunting, and can be lazy in general.

I play like a Cello but with a silence echo

> Cello strings were traditionally made from [catgut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catgut). Cats can be quite silent and stealthy.

I am long like a Metro but not quite the rainbow

> [Longcat](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/longcat) is long and about the shape of a train car. [Nyan Cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyan_Cat) is not a rainbow, but one trails behind him wherever he goes.

Comment: Not the answer but I like your explanation.  Longcat isn't long enough =)

Answer (score 1):

How about

> Trochee

Because

> A trochee is a two-syllable word, consisting of first a stressed (or "long") syllable and then an unstressed ("short") syllable. Fast then slow, noise then silence, long then not quite as long, and the answer is a fit for the meter because "trochee" is itself a trochee. And of course, all of the two-syllable nouns in the riddle are trochees.

Comment: I like your answer, but I guess Trochee doesn't necessary be Fast then slow